# Oracle Timestamp, Max and Minimal Values

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp

I was searching, also in the Oracle Doc, for the following:

- *What is the range for Timestamp in Oracle?*

I know for date it is -4712, Jan-01 to 9999 Dec-31, but what for Timestamp?

Anyone a clue or hint where I can search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always just try it:

```
SQL> select to_timestamp( '9999-12-31 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' ) from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP('9999-12-3123:59:59','YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
31-DEC-99 11.59.59.000000000 PM
```

and:

```
SQL> select to_timestamp( '9999-12-31 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' )+1 from dual;
select to_timestamp( '9999-12-31 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' )+1 from dual
                                                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

Comment: Thank you, i had no oracle server nearby to try, but it should be documented anywhere anyway.

Comment: Trying to find the maxium/minimum value of timestamp in Oracle is extreamly hard because fraction of seconds usually truncated or rounded by default. And the error message itself is missleading. You cannot actually specify `-4713` as year.

Answer (score 3):

It would be surprising if the range for the DATE portion of a TIMESTAMP was smaller than the range for a DATE, so it should be:

```
-4712-01-01 00:00:00  to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999
```

That assumes no time zone; the UTC value is probably constrained to that range, but someone in an Eastern time zone might manage to see a data value on 1000-01-01 in their time zone.

It is hard to find definitive data off Oracle's site.  The best I found in a casual survey was:

- http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/datatypes.php

There are probably others.

---

I found a quote which says:

> TIMESTAMP Datatype
>
> The TIMESTAMP datatype is an extension of the DATE datatype. It stores the year,
> month, and day of the DATE datatype, plus hour, minute, and second values.

Comment: Ahh okay, so it hast basically the same boundaries. Thank You.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefdttlimits.html This links to a list of date type limits. Seems a bit hidden, though.

Comment: @MalteHartwig that link is NOT related to Oracle Database data types

Comment: The fractional seconds can be 9 digits. therefore valid timestamp range should be from `-4712-01-01 00:00:00.000000000` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999999`