# LocalDate.MAX can't be persisted in Oracle db

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

When I try to persist `LocalDate.MAX`, I am getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Invalid year value; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid year value
```

The definition of `LocalDate.MAX` is:

```
public static final LocalDate MAX = LocalDate.of(Year.MAX_VALUE, 12, 31);
```

whereas `Year.MAX_VALUE` is:

```
public static final int MAX_VALUE = 999_999_999;
```

As a sidenote, H2 doesn't have any problem

Why is it like that?

Is there any workaround to make it working?

Comment: It's just typical insert statement. Hibernate's BasicBinder logs: binding parameter [9] as [DATE] - [ 628-12-09] for java object's LocalDate = +999999999-12-31.. it is strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefdttlimits.html) say that the Oracle date types accept years up to 9999. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761236/oracle-timestamp-max-and-minimal-values) also deals with this topic.

You could work around this by storing those dates as Number (i.e. milliseconds)?

You could also try to store your date as text and parse it back, but that would add overhead and would be more difficult to compare in queries.

An alternative would be creating your own MaxDate in some Util class.

Comment: I used private static final LocalDate NEVERENDING = LocalDate.of(9999, Month.DECEMBER, 31) after all

Comment: @PatrikMihalčin yes, that is the simplest fix, and should work long enough for any software. Though it would be funny to imagine the y10k bug, hitting Oracle databases worldwide ;D